# Trying to parse an XML file with Python - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, xml

I'm working with XML and Python for the first time. The ultimate goal is to send a request to a REST service, receive a response in XML, and parse the values and send emails depending on what was returned. However, the REST service is not yet in place, so for now I'm experimenting with an XML file saved on my C drive.

I have a simple bit of code, and I'm confused about why it isn't working.

This is my xml file ("XMLTest.xml"):

```
<Response>
    <exitCode>1</exitCode>
    <fileName>C:/Something/</fileName>
    <errors>
        <error>Error generating report</error>
    </errors>
</Response>
```

This is my code so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

something = open("C:/XMLTest.xml")
something = minidom.parse(something)

nodeList = []
for node in something.getElementsByTagName("Response"):  
    nodeList.extend(t.nodeValue for t in node.childNodes)
print nodeList
```

But the results that print out are...

```
[u'\n\t', None, u'\n\t', None, u'\n\t', None, u'\n']
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to get the node values. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a built-in method in Python to convert an xml file to an object or dictionary? I'd like to get all the values, preferably with the names attached.

Comment: That is what I would expect the code you have posted to print. What would you like the results to be?

Comment: @Katrielalex - I'm trying to get the values of the nodes - 1, "C:/Something", etc. How can I accomplish this? Is there a better way? Is there an easy way to get some sort of dictionary or object with the node names and values?

Comment: See below. Unfortunately there's no default way to cast it to a dictionary, because XML is too flexible for there to be a sensible way of doing so. You have to hardwire the indices of the nodes (for instance, what would happen if there were two `exitCode` nodes?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
doc = '''<Response>
    <exitCode>1</exitCode>
    <fileName>C:/Something/</fileName>
    <errors>
        <error>Error generating report</error>
    </errors>
</Response>'''

from xml.dom import minidom

something = minidom.parseString( doc )

nodeList = [ ]
for node in something.getElementsByTagName( "Response" ):
    response = { }
    response[ "exit code" ] = node.getElementsByTagName( "exitCode" )[ 0 ].childNodes[ 0 ].nodeValue
    response[ "file name" ] = node.getElementsByTagName( "fileName" )[ 0 ].childNodes[ 0 ].nodeValue
    errors = node.getElementsByTagName( "errors" )[ 0 ].getElementsByTagName( "error" )
    response[ "errors" ] = [ error.childNodes[ 0 ].nodeValue for error in errors ]

    nodeList.append( response )

import pprint
pprint.pprint( nodeList )
```

yields

```
[{'errors': [u'Error generating report'],
  'exit code': u'1',
  'file name': u'C:/Something/'}]
```

Comment: This works for this specific example, but I was looking for something a bit more generic that could parse any xml file into some sort of Python structure...

Comment: @froadie: That function already exists; it's called `xml.dom.minidom.parse`. There is no builtin Python structure which can adequately represent XML, so it defines its own structures.

Comment: This is a great solution to the problem.  If you want something more robust, you might want to go with `xml.etree.ElementTree` over `xml.dom.minidom`, because it tends to involve less syntax with nested traversals.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just starting out with xml and python, and have no compelling reason to use DOM, I strongly suggest you have a look at the ElementTree api (implemented in the standard library in [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html))

To give you a taste:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse('C:/XMLTest.xml')
response = tree.getroot()
exitcode = response.find('exitCode').text
filename = response.find('fileName').text
errors = [i.text for i in response.find('errors')]
```

(if you need more power - xpath, validation, xslt etc... - you can even switch to [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), which implements the same API, but with a lot of extras)

Answer (score 0):

You're not thinking about the XML from the DOM standpoint. Namely, 'C:/Something' isn't the nodevalue of the element whose tagname is 'fileName'; it's the nodevalue of the text node that is the first child of the element whose tagname is 'fileName'.

What I recommend you do is play around with it a little more in python itself: start python.

> > > from xml.dom import minidom
> > >
> > > x = minidom.parseString('<Response><filename>C:/</filename>>')
> > >
> > > x.getElementsByTagName('Response')
> > >       ...
> > >       x.getElementsByTagName('Response')[0].childNodes[0]
> > >       ...

and so forth. You'll get a quick appreciation for how the document is being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend my library [xml2obj](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534109-xml-to-python-data-structure/). It is way cleaner than DOM. The "library" has only 84 lines of code you can embed anywhere.

```
In [185]: resp = xml2obj(something)

In [186]: resp.exitCode
Out[186]: u'1'

In [187]: resp.fileName
Out[187]: u'C:/Something/'

In [188]: len(resp.errors)
Out[188]: 1

In [189]: for node in resp.errors:
   .....:     print node.error
   .....:
   .....:
Error generating report
```